# Why nodeos and keosd url format can't be localhost now?

Tags: cleos

When I use the `cleos -u http://localhost:8888`, it will cause error, but if I use `cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:8888`, that is ok.

What's the problem?

Comment: What error does it cause? It seems to work fine for me

Comment: invalid content length, my version is v1.0.10

Answer (score 1):

Should work, but I believe `eosio::http_plugin` is not properly validating the case where `host` is `localhost`. Try:

```
$ cleos -u http://localhost:8888 --http-validate-host=false
```

or add `http-validate-host=false` to the `config.ini` for `nodeos`.